# Is Tesa packing tape the same as some tubeless tapes?

Tags: tubeless, frugal, rim-tape

I've seen Tesa 4289 packing tape marketed as an equivalent to cycling tubeless tape. It looks very similar, to me, to some cycle-branded tapes. Some report that it is the same as tubeless tape such as Stan's, while it is significantly cheaper.

Is Tesa 4289 an identical product to bike tubeless products?

(related: if so, is there any disadvantage to buying a bulk roll i.e. 66m in length?)

Comment: I guess if it works, its perfecrtly good as tubeless tape.  And if its cheap, you can use more and still come out ahead.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Tesa 4289 is polypropylene. Tubeless rim tape is Kapton, which is a polyimide. The prices I'm seeing for tubeless rim tape are pretty much in line with the prices I see for Kapton tape not marketed specifically as rim tape. Kapton is available in different thicknesses, which will affect the price. I'm not sure what the typical thickness for rim tape is.

I'm sure people have used all kinds of stuff as tubeless rim tape, and maybe some of it even works, but they're not identical.

Comment: I don't think all tubeless tapes are Kapton. I know the Stans is a rebranded 3M polypropylene tape for sure. Kapton tapes tend to have that golden color, which not all tapes do.